# Разбиение таблицы (TSQL) по дате заказа

Tags: sql, sql-server, big-data

Есть таблица, куда попадают заказы. У заказа есть уникальный ключ (id), некоторые данные, и дата заказа (orderDate). Заказов бывает очень много, они не только приходят, но и обновляются (например, если изменился статус заказа). Хорошо бы сделать автоматическое секционирование таблицы по номерам дня (либо номерам недели), чтобы ускорить поиск и обновление необходимого заказа. Идея в том, чтобы когда в таблицу приходил заказ, он был записан в определенную "подтаблицу" в соответствии со своим orderDate. Как это сделать, если я использую SQL Server?

Comment: Используйте секционирование (partitioning). См. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: А насколько много заказов? Что-то прежде чем думать про секционирование, вы уверены, что затык скорости именно в объеме данных, а не кривом/запросе и отсутствии индексов? Индексы там тоже ведь у вас разные есть, бывают частичные какие-то, так что версия СУБД также имеет смысл.

Comment: Обычно делят по месяцам, но, конечно, зависит от того, сколько записей и т.д.

Comment: @Akina, я смотрел эту статью. Проблема в том, что тут секционирование происходит вручную, т.е мне необходимо прописывать каждый конкретный день самому. Я же хочу, чтобы это происходило автоматически.  в oracle Db это делается так
"create table test(id number, date_create date default sysdate not null)
partition by range (date_create)
INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(PARTITION FIRST VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2016-11-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
);"

Comment: *секционирование происходит вручную, т.е мне необходимо прописывать каждый конкретный день самому.* У SQL Server планировщик имеется. Создайте задание на формирование дополнительных секций заранее (например, раз в месяц создавайте секции на следующий месяц).